# How to establish a connection with SAP ABAP workbench with SSIS

Tags: ssis, connection-string, abap, sap-erp

I am new to this, could anybody help me to establish a connection with SAP ECC 6.0 ABAP workbench using SSIS.

I didn't find any article related to this, please help me on this, we are looking for who knows knowledge on this.

Badly looking for it.

Comment: This question was already asked and closed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a ABAP Workbench to connect SAP ECC db. Which DB engine are you using for ECC? You just need to create a db/os user on the existing ECC db engine. Generally, it uses OS-level authentication. For example, it is using Windows authentication for MSSQL.